# Test function called when object deleted

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have the following class `Request_manager.h`

```
class Request_manager {
public:
    class Ticket {
    protected:
        explicit Ticket(System_time start_time);
        virtual ~Ticket();
    };

    struct ticket_element_{
        int app;
        std::shared_ptr <Request_manager::Ticket> ticket;
    };

    class Tickets_Queue{
    private:
        std::queue <ticket_element_> m_queue;

    public:
        void push(ticket_element_ ticket);
        static void notify();
    };

    static Tickets_Queue ticket_queue;
    static int num_connected() { return m_connected; }

private:
    static int m_connected;
};
```

In `Request_manager.cpp` I have something like:

```
Request_manager::Ticket::~Ticket() {
    Lock lock(accept_mutex);
    running_set.erase(running_set.find(m_key));
    --m_handled;
    --m_accepted;
    --m_connected;
    ticket_queue.notify();
}
```

Which basically means that every time a `Request_manager::Ticket` is deleted a call to  `ticket_queue`.

I want to test this behavior in `gMock` but I do not know how to approach the problem because if I create a mock of `Request_manager::Ticket` then how do I check than in the destructor of this mock `ticket_queue` is called?

Comment: Wouldn't you be testing a **real** ticket? not a mock.

Comment: The Request_manager was not designed to be testable in that fashion.  It is tightly coupled with its dependencies.  To make it unit testable, it should have dependency injection rather than hard-coded dependencies.

Comment: Hej @Eljay do you have a small example around my code to understand what you mean?

Comment: Because following example in https://www.codymorterud.com/design/2018/09/07/dependency-injection-cpp.html cannot understand how could I apply it to my specific problem

Comment: Jonathan Boccara wrote a blog post on C++ and [dependency injection](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/06/07/write-your-own-dependency-injection-container/).